# Ember incementProperty on an interval

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Two-part problem:

First part

I have a "seconds" (as in time) property that I want to increment with two different events on the same element:

1. Click to increment
2. Click-and-hold (mousedown) to increment every 1/10th second.

From what I've read, the best way to get two events on the same element is to create a component and use the built-in event handlers. So I've done that, BUT using a setInterval in my mousedown event creates a scoping issue where 'this' becomes the window and incrementProperty can no longer access its model.

Here's my component code. The click event works beautifully (without the mousedown).

```
App.PaceAdjustUpComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    click: function() {
        var ps = this.get('model.ps'),
            pm = this.get('model.pm');
        this.incrementProperty('ps');
        this.send('calculateTime');
        if (ps >= 59) {
            this.incrementProperty('pm');
            this.set('model.ps', 0);
        }
    },
    mouseDown: function() {
        var interval;
        var ps = this.get('model.ps'),
            pm = this.get('model.pm');
        interval = window.setInterval(function() {
            ps + 1;
            this.send('calculateTime');
            if (ps >= 59) {
                this.incrementProperty('pm');
                this.set('model.ps', 0);
            }
        }, 100);
    },
    mouseUp: function() {
        window.clearInterval(interval);
    }
    });
```

Second Part:

This

```
        this.send('calculateTime');
```

was originally part of some code in a controller, and there it worked fine, but I need to be able to send that method to the controller so that when my incrementer works, it also fires 'calculateTime'.

I'm a noob. Totally green. Need lots of hand-holding. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're essentially out of scope. And if you want to send an action out of a component you need to hook it up while creating the component and use `sendAction` instead of `send` (`sendAction` will send the action to the hooked up action name used while creating the component)

```
{{pace-adjust-up model=model calculateTime='calculateFooooo'}}

App.PaceAdjustUpComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  click: function() {
    this.increment();  
  },
  mouseDown: function() {
    var interval, self = this;
    interval = window.setInterval(function() {
      self.increment();
    }, 100);
    this.set('interval', interval);
  },
  mouseUp: function() {
    window.clearInterval(this.get('interval'));
  },
  increment: function(){
    var ps = this.get('model.ps'),
        pm = this.get('model.pm');
    this.incrementProperty('model.ps');
    this.sendAction('calculateTime');
    if (ps >= 59) {
      this.incrementProperty('model.pm');
      this.set('model.ps', 0);
    }
  }
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qitohavu/1/edit

Comment: is there a reason why you'll create a `self` variable instead of `bind()`ing the function?

Comment: I implemented the code from your jsbin, and everything appears to be firing correctly, but now I get the following error in the console: "Uncaught Error: Property set failed: object in path "model" could not be found or was destroyed."

Comment: @herom, historically bind has been slower than closure in chrome and self makes just as much sense to me as bind does, but beside that, there is no reason.

Comment: @fedoroffn, what model are you sending into the component?  can you create an example to show what you're seeing?

Comment: @kingpin2k, I'm not sure how to go about creating an example without re-creating my entire app. The setup is pretty simple, though: I'm including the components ('time-increment', 'time-decrement', etc) in my `race` template, and the `race` route's model looks like this: [link](http://jsbin.com/kireguna/1/) . The component didn't have any trouble getting properties from the model before I refactored to your suggestion, so I'm guessing we have a different scope issue now?

Comment: Yes! It's _exactly_ like that. Thanks so much!